# Live Message Wall with Social Profile Pics

Tags: php, sql, facebook, twitter

I want to create a page that users are able to post a message and it then displays on a wall next to the submit form. That is pretty straight forward to do with PHP and SQL I know.

The hard part is that I want to link their Facebook or Twitter account to display their profile pic next to their message.

It's basically a shout out wall with user's profile pics and speech bubbles next to them.

Any ideas how I can do it or have you seen any examples of this?

Comment: How do you determine the user account for each user ?

Comment: Maybe [Facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) (for Websites) might better suit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @luschn points out, you will need to authenticate your users.

### Twitter

You will need to use the `GET` [`users/show`](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners) endpoint.

### Facebook

You will need to use the `GET` [`/me/picture`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/picture) endpoint.

PHP SDK

To do this with facebook you can easily use the php sdk they provide

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Another tutorial, if the Facebook docs are not enough: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

After that, use the [`/me/picture`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/picture) endpoint to get the profile picture.

The JavaScript SDK is definitely recommended, it is much easier to handle and the usability is much better than using the PHP SDK - because you don´t need to redirect the user for the authorization.

---

For Twitter, you just need to supply the username - for example: https://twitter.com/[username]/profile_image?size=original

No authorization needed for Twitter, there is an alternative with authorization too: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show